# How to capture output of -- restore verifyonly from disk ="c:\common\backups" in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, scripting

I have a command **restore verifyonly from disk ="c:\common\backups"** in my sql.
command =**restore verifyonly from disk ="c:\common\backups"**

And i have to verify if the command executed, if not then i shud break out of my code, so how to capture output of above command in sql sever, so after comparing its output i can proceed with my code.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204698/how-to-restore-bak-only-if-its-good

Comment: Thanks mate! i guess that would work out for me!